# Динамическая подстановка запроса в JasperReports

Tags: java, jasperreports

Новичок в JR, пытаюсь разобраться. Есть приложение, которое выводит данные из БД в зависимости от выбранных условий (отмеченных флагов), причем  комбинаций этих условий очень много.  В JR Studio создан шаблон отчета, причем в качестве запроса прописан вариант запроса из приложения, соответственно, независимо от того, какие условия выбраны в приложении (и выведены на экран), в отчет всегда попадают условия, прописанные при его создании. Как я понимаю, нужно как то передавать в отчет существующий запрос (в принципе достаточно передавать только блок "WHERE", так как условия меняются только там) перед его созданием. Правильно ли это, и если правильно, то как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть кому то поможет. Сделал так:
1. Сделал парсер jrxml файла, в котором подставляю нужный запрос

```
String sourceFileName = getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources/jasper/Users.jrxml";

try {

            fXmlFile = new File(sourceFileName);
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

            //optional, but recommended            
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("queryString");

            // Get the queryString element by tag name directly
            Node qNode = doc.getElementsByTagName("queryString").item(0);

            NodeList list = qNode.getChildNodes();

            for(int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = list.item(i);
                //System.out.println("node = " + node + "   node.getTextContent() = " + node.getTextContent());
                if(node.getNodeName().equals("#cdata-section")) {                        
                    node.setTextContent("select * from s_users WHERE s_users.DOLZHNOST LIKE 'Консультант'");
                }                
            }
            //Запишем содержимое в xml файл
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File(sourceFileName));
            transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2. Компилирую в jasper файл и формирую отчет

   String sourceFileName = getProperty("user.dir")+"/src/main/resources/jasper/Users.jrxml";
   JasperReport jReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(sourceFileName);
               JasperPrint jPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jReport, new HashMap(), new DAOimpl().getCon());
               JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jPrint, PATH + "users.html");

где new DAOimpl().getCon() - connection к БД

Comment: Может я не очень понял вопрос, но почему нельзя было просто параметр передвавать?

Comment: Наверное можно было, но я не очень разобрался с параметром.